# how to replicate variables on multiple locales in Chapel

Tags: replication, hpc, chapel

I'm wondering that is there an easy way to make a copy of a global variable on each locale so that later each locale will directly access its local copy instead of accessing the original variable stored in locale0 ?

thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and why do you want to do this? Let's make sure we're not trying to [shave a yak](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2005/03/dont_shave_that.html) here...

Comment: I'm trying to localize some frequently accessed global variables to gain some performance benefit. (I'm assuming global variables are allocated in locale0 and accessing them from other locales results in communication, right?) However, after localizing them, it did not give me speedup(maybe 1%) as I expected, so I suppose accessing the global variables from other locales doesn't incur too much overhead? @dcsohl

Comment: If the globals can be declared as constants rather than variables, they will be replicated across locales at the program's start-up time (at least for simple types—a current effort is looking into extending this to more complicated types).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**`ReplicatedDist`**](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/modules/dists/ReplicatedDist.html) distribution to get a copy of a variable per locale.  There is a module [**`UtilReplicatedVar`**](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/modules/standard/UtilReplicatedVar.html) to simplify its use.

```
use UtilReplicatedVar;

var regularInt = 42;

// rcDomain is declared in UtilReplicatedVar.  It maps
// one int value to each locale
var repInt: [rcDomain] int;

// Other types can be replicated as well.  Here a
// heterogeneous tuple containing an integer,
// real, and complex is replicated
var repTuple: [rcDomain] (int, real, complex);

// Assign 42 to the replicated int on all locales
rcReplicate(repVar, regularInt);

// Access the local copy of the replicated var.
// The first form must use 1 as the index.
repVar[1] = 0;
writeln(rcLocal(repVar));

// Access the local complex component of the tuple
writeln(repTuple[1](3));

// Access a remote copy.
rcRemote(repVar, remoteLocale);
```

Comment: I have another question: are global variables (declared outside the main function) all allocated on locale0 and need wide pointers to access them from other locales?  What about the param and const? I found little performance benefit by localizing those...(not by using UtilReplicatedVar since it gives much worse performance)

Comment: Yes, module-level variables are conceptually on Locale[0], and from other locales need to be accessed remotely through a wide pointer.  There are some exceptions such as distributed arrays that implement an optimization we call privatization.  Constants with primitive or record types are replicated by the compiler as an optimization.  Params code generate as literal values and don't represent any memory location during execution; any locale can refer to these literals without communication.